# How to get Broadcast message from connected Devices on same network?

Tags: java, android, sockets, broadcast

How we can read or receive Broadcast message in Android WiFi network  sent from Same network (Router)  using  UDP packets . I am trying to use MultiSocket and socket for receiving Packets, but I am not able to get Broadcast message sent from Network.

Also I am testing the broadcast message **Wireshark**. Its working fine, but I am not able receive packets on Android Device.

So my question is how we can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!